# Python Select Multiple Options Dropdown

Tags: python, html, forms, form-submit

I want to loop and select all the months and years in the code so I can save the data. The html is as follows:

```
<label for="reportSelectMonth">Month:</label>
<select name="reportSelectMonth" id="reportSelectMonth">
    <option value="">Select</option>

    <option value="1" >January</option>

    <option value="2" >February</option>

    <option value="3" >March</option>

    <option value="4" >April</option>

    <option value="5" >May</option>

    <option value="6" >June</option>

    <option value="7" selected>July</option>

    <option value="8" >August</option>

    <option value="9" >September</option>

    <option value="10" >October</option>

    <option value="11" >November</option>

    <option value="12" >December</option>

</select>
<label for="reportSelectYear">Year:</label>
<select name="reportSelectYear" id="reportSelectYear">
    <option value="">Select</option>

    <option value="2012" >2012</option>

    <option value="2013" >2013</option>

    <option value="2014" >2014</option>

    <option value="2015" >2015</option>

    <option value="2016" selected>2016</option>

</select>





import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'website'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

I have the website that I would like to scrape but I need to select the options and submit. How can I proceed?

Comment: _"and submit it"_ - you are asking about how to submit a html form?  The question is tagged as `python`, are you instead asking how to extract the data from html document in Python?  In either case please show your attempt so far

Comment: @FujiApple I wrote a code in Python to extract data from a html document already. While I was trying to apply the code to another website, I faced the trouble since this website has a dropbox and I would have to select the options using code so I guess I am asking how to submit a html form.

Comment: I've submitted an edit to add the appropriate tags to the question to the right people may see it.  Nonetheless you'll need to provide your sample code before anyone can help you resolve your issue.

Comment: @FujiApple I have posted my sample code. Thank for your advice.